# Is Firefox Private Network available in iOS

Tags: firefox

From webpage https://private-network.firefox.com/, I know that Firefox Private Network  is available in Firefox windows client, is Firefox Private Network funation available in the Firefox App of iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the webpage:

> This extension is currently available to US desktop users only.

This means that it is only available for desktop Firefox.

However, the extension is allegedly based on the same infrastructure as CloudFlare's [Warp](https://blog.cloudflare.com/1111-warp-better-vpn/) VPN service, which is currently being rolled out to the "1.1.1.1" app if you have it installed.

The Warp VPN appears to be available on iOS *and* in all countries.